# Using Javascript to read from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm pulling some JSON data from an API source into Google Sheets and getting ready to push it into an array. I've used `JSON.parse` to put the data into the following format:

```
[{EmployeeRef={name=value, value=value}, NameOf=value, Hours=value, TxnDate=value, HourlyRate=value, Minutes=value, PayrollItemRef=value, SyncToken=value, BillableStatus=value, sparse=value, MetaData={CreateTime=value, LastUpdatedTime=value}, domain=value, ItemRef={name=value, value=value}, ID=value, CustomerRef={name=value, value=value}, Taxable=value}, etc.]
```

When I try to push it into the empty array, however, I'm getting an error. Here's what I'm using to push it into the array:

```
results.forEach(function(elem,z) {
    output.push([elem["TxnDate"],elem["EmployeeRef"]['name'],elem["CustomerRef"]['name'],elem["ItemRef"]['name'],elem["BillableStatus"],elem["HourlyRate"],elem["Hours"],elem["Minutes"],elem["Description"]]);
  });
```

The error I get is

> "TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from undefined. (line 62, file
>   "Code")".

So I thought I would just drop in and check one of the sets of values in the array. But when I run the following code:

```
Logger.log(results[0]['EmployeeRef']['name']);
```

I get:

> [18-12-06 13:27:41:465 EST] value
>
> [18-12-06 13:27:41:878 EST] value

Why am I getting two values from that? I thought that results[0] would just get me one "row" of the array, so to speak. That looks to me as though it is the 'EmployeeRef' and 'name' values from results[0] *and* results[1].

Is this why I'm getting the TypeError message? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `CustomerRef` object inside your array of objects, and that's why when trying to add to the array `elem["CustomerRef"]['name']` you're getting that error.

(It's not related to `EmployeeRef` which is there)

You should probably just add some kind of `null` check before accessing the `name` parameter of an inner object inside your array.
Something similar to this:

```
results.forEach(function(elem, z) {
    output.push(
        [elem["TxnDate"],
         elem["EmployeeRef"] ? elem["EmployeeRef"]["name"] : null,
         elem["CustomerRef"] ? elem["CustomerRef"]["name"] : null,
         elem["ItemRef"] ? elem["ItemRef"]["name"] : null,
         elem["BillableStatus"],
         elem["HourlyRate"],
         elem["Hours"],
         elem["Minutes"],
         elem["Description"]
    ]);
});
```

Note: This will add `null` values to your array if the `EmployeeRef` object or the `CustomerRef` object doesn't exist, but it is less likely to throw an error.